# How do I install Catalyst::Plugin::Session?

Tags: perl, cpan

I would like to create a session using the Catalyst::Plugin::Session module, but I am not sure how to install it in the server as I am connecting the server with putty.

Please let me know how to install it.

Comment: @downvoter: dare to comment

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: IF you know the answer please do it and not downvote @ i alarmed alien

Comment: I didn't downvote. Your question came up for review after being flagged as low quality, and I gave a suggestion for improving the question, which will increase the likelihood of someone responding.

Answer (score 1):

Perl modules are installed with a CPAN client, usually `cpan` or `cpanm`. For example:

```
$ cpan
<whole lot of initial conf questions>
cpan[1]> install Catalyst::Plugin::Session
<whole lot of installing>
cpan[2]> exit
$
```

Google 'install Perl modules with CPAN'. But these modules are almost certainly already installed if Catalyst is.

On the other hand, if you're asking how to configure your application to use this plugin, you simply add it to your list of plugins in your main program, eg:

```
package MyApp;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Catalyst qw(
        Session
        Session::Store::FastMmap
        Session::State::Cookie
        ...
        );
```

This is covered at some length in [the very fine Catalyst Tutorials](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Manual::Tutorial).